# Non-perturbative approach to high-energy physics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, non-perturbative, lattice-gauge-theory

I know that main numerical approach to modeling high-energy physics events are Monte-Carlo event generators. But they are using perturbative description of collision and decay processes of particles.

On other hand we have Lattice QCD - a fully non-perturbative approach to quantum chromodynamics at low energies. It was very successful to investigating confinement and calculating masses of hadrons.

But my question is following - can we apply lattice techniques to simulate high-energy events from the first principles?
E.g Proton-proton collision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current day calculations, Lattice-QCD usually refers to calculations in Euclidean time, after wick rotation. The reason for this is that it transforms the usual complex measure (that has lots of oscillations), to a well-defined probability distribution:
$$\text{exp}\left(i\int d^4 x F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu}\right) \mapsto  \text{exp}\left(-\int d^4 x F^E_{\mu \nu}F^E_{\mu \nu}\right)  $$
where I write $F^E$ just to remind us these are in the Euclidean picture, the $\mu,\nu$ indices are Euclidean signature now. This is done because the [sign problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_sign_problem) prevents efficient simulation of complex measures, and a completely positive measure has many effective Monte Carlo methods to simulate it such as [HMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_Monte_Carlo).

Because of this, some quantities such as masses of hadrons or matrix elements are relatively straight-forward to extract from Lattice-QCD calculations, but some quantities such as those arising from real-time scattering are more tricky. It's still possible through methods such as [Luscher's finite-volume formalism](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321391903666), it's a fairly 'indirect' extraction of physical quantities though (somehow, the energy states of multi-particle states in finite volume are related to the infinite volume scattering matrix elements). In practice, people do investigations of meson-scattering on the lattice, I believe a hot topic right now is three-body interactions as well.

Ignoring practicality however, in principle there's nothing stopping us from doing real-time lattice-QCD calculations, it's just really computationally expensive. People work on using Machine Learning or Quantum Computers to try and speed up this kind of calculation.